ksp in kotlin multiplatform setting output directory
In my kotlin multi platform project I need to generate code using ksp. This all works except my generated code ends up in the jvmMain build directory. The purpose of the generate code is to be used in the jsMain or commonMain source sets which won't have Java dependencies. I've tried writing copy tasks which end up as a lot of messy gradle so I think I must be missing something.
My code generates correctly in:
./build/generated/ksp/jvm/jvmMain/kotlin/com/etc

and I just need it in commonMain so I can use it in non-jvm projects.  I'm looking for the way to do this in ksp before resorting to a copy task or script.
My ksp.output directory seems to be ignored here:
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "2.0.20-RC"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

 

kotlin {
    jvm()
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            binaries.executable()

            distribution {
                outputDirectory = File("${projectDir}/build/distributions")
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")
               
            }
        }
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.5.0")
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
                implementation(project(":ksp")) //this is my ksp module with the code generator
               
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    add("kspCommonMainMetadata", project(":ksp"))
    add("kspJvm", project(":ksp"))
    add("kspJvmTest", project(":ksp"))
}

ksp {
     arg("ksp.outputDir", "${projectDir}/src/commonMain/kotlin")
}


Solved it.
My Gradle was correct but in my implementation of the code generator i needed to reference it:
val dir = env.options["ksp.outputDir"]

You have to write the generated classes using a path otherwise it'll default to the build directory.
